# MessageConversionException during serialization in spring-kafka?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

To show what I mean I make simple project.

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is all kafka configuration in code:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaSerializationConfig implements SmartInitializingSingleton {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public KafkaSerializationConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
        AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(kafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties());

        List<NewTopic> newTopics = new ArrayList<>();
        newTopics.add(new NewTopic("demo", 2, (short) 2));
        client.createTopics(newTopics);

        client.close();
    }

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModules(new Jdk8Module(), new JavaTimeModule());

    public static class KafkaSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
        public KafkaSerializer() {
            super(mapper);
        }
    }

    public static class KafkaDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {
        public KafkaDeserializer() {
            super(mapper);
        }
    }

}
```

`application.yml` file:

```
    spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: sample-cutter
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: "*"
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
      value-deserializer: com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.config.KafkaSerializationConfig.KafkaDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer
      value-serializer: com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.config.KafkaSerializationConfig.KafkaSerializer
```

So this app can be up and its works. But let's try to use it. Let's image we have two services: the server and the client. So we have two classes with the same fields:

DTO for the client:

```
public class GettingUser {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public GettingUser() {
    }

    public GettingUser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

DTO for the server:

```
public class SendingUser {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public SendingUser() {
    }

    public SendingUser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And eventually let's try to use it:

```
@RestController
public class SpringSerializationDemoController {

    private final KafkaTemplate<Long, SendingUser> template;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public SpringSerializationDemoController(KafkaTemplate<Long, SendingUser> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @GetMapping("/start-demo")
    public String startDemo() {
        SendingUser user = new SendingUser("John", "Smith");
        template.send("demo", user);
        return "OK";
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "demo")
    public void consumeCutSample(GettingUser user) {
        logger.info("Got user: {}", user);
    }
}
```

I can see exception which show my app can't cast `SendingUser` to `GettingUser`.
Exception:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.controller.SpringSerializationDemoController.consumeCutSample(com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.GettingUser)]
Bean [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.controller.SpringSerializationDemoController@53601a9c]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser] to [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.GettingUser] for GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser] to [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.GettingUser] for GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2037) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2025) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1924) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1851) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1748) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1472) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1135) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1038) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser] to [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.GettingUser] for GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:340) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1992) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1974) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1911) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser] to [com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.GettingUser] for GenericMessage [payload=com.example.springkafkasimpledemo.domain.SendingUser@36f41365, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@74a44b4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, kafka_receivedTopic=demo, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1604226244969, kafka_groupId=sample-cutter}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:145) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:910) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:329) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

But why does it do it? My object mapper doesn't use types. I can see it in my console:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic demo
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}
```

Can't understand why spring-kafka tries to cast SendingUser to GettingUser.

Comment: Your user objects are the exact same, why do you need both? In any case, spring knows you sent a SendingUser - `payload=`, so that explains why it's trying to convert

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, that's right for this single app. But usually I have several services and they should communicate with `dto`. In this way it's the problem.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can't understand how can it be in payload? I can see the data of message in console. Where kafka storage info about class? Can I see it in terminal?

Comment: It might be in the kafka message headers. Or it would be known by spring annotations, because you have one KafkaTemplate which is mapped to both your producer and consumer, whose value is not a GettingUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Spring JSON (de)serializer (both sides), you need to configure the type mapping - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#json-serde

Map the source class to a token on the sending side and map the token to the required class on the receiving side.

Or you can disable the use of headers in the deserializer and configure a default type. See `setUseTypeHeaders()`.

**EDIT**

For more sophisticated types, e.g. generics, you should [configure the deserializer to call a method that returns a `JavaType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods).

e.g. for a `List<Foo>`:

```java
public static JavaType returnType(String topic, byte[] data, Headers headers) {
    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, Foo.class);
}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.demo.Application.returnType
```

Use a `TypeReference` or `constructParametricType` for your `Event<SourceFile>`. See [Spring Kafka Consumer consumed message as LinkedHashMap hence automatically converting BigDecimal to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684929/spring-kafka-consumer-consumed-message-as-linkedhashmap-hence-automatically-conv/64685936#64685936)

Comment: Or you can disable the use of type headers altogether.

Comment: Russel ok, got you. Thanks! I have one more question. What if I want to get value with generic? I wrote something like that `class FileEventKafkaDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Event<SourceFile>>` but actually in debug I can see that I got `Event<LinkedHashMap>` message.

Comment: Great! Works fine. But what can I do if I need to take different generic type in different kafka listeners? Do I have to create multiple consumerFactory or there is a way to declare it in one place?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions; usually knowing the topic is sufficient; since version 2.5, you can add `String topic` as the first parameter to the `JavaType` method (see the answer I linked to for an example). If that's not enough, you can override the method name in each listener `@KafkaListener(..., properties = "spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.Foo.otherMethod")`.