# Spring Kafka Consumer consumed message as LinkedHashMap hence automatically converting BigDecimal to double

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using annotation based spring kafka listener to consume the kafka messages, and code is as below

1. Consuming Employee Object

```java
Class Employee{
private String name;
private String address;
private Object account;
//getters
//setters
}
```

2. Account object decides on runtime whether it's Saving Account or Current Account etc.

```java
Class SavingAcc{
private BigDecimal balance;

}
Class CurrentAcc{
private BigDecimal balance;
private BigDecimal limit;
}
```

3. Saving & Current Account having BigDecimal Fields to store balance.
4. Hence while sending Employee object from Kafka producer, all the fields are correctly mapped and appears in correct format of BigDecimal, etc.
5. But while consuming the Employee object in another service, account object is appearing as LinkedHashMap and BigDecimal fields are converted to Double. which is causing issues.
6. As per my understanding, the main reason can be as
   a) Declaration of account as Object type instead of specific type
   b) Or the deserializer should be provided more specifically. [I have already give Employee.class as type to kafka receiver deserializer, so Employee fields are correctly mapped but account fields wrong].

```java
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Employee> consumerFactory(){
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Employee.class));
}
```

Need help on how to map or how to get the account fields properly deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Generics and a custom [`JavaType` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods).

```java
Class Employee<T> {
private String name;
private String address;
private T account;
//getters
//setters
}
```

```
JavaType withCurrent = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(Employee.class, CurrentAcc.class);

JavaType withSaving = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(Employee.class, SavingAcc.class);

public static JavaType determineType(String topic, byte[] data, Headers headers) {
    // If it's a current account
        return withCurrent;
    // else 
        return withSaving;
}
```

If you construct the deserializer yourself use

```java
deser.setTypeResolver(MyClass::determineType);
```

When configuring with properties.

```
spring.json.value.type.method=com.mycompany.MyCass.determineType
```

You have to inspect the data or headers (or topic) to determine which type you want.

**EDIT**

Here is a complete example. In this case, I pass a type hint in the `Account` object, but an alternative would be to set a header on the producer side.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class JacksonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JacksonApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Data
    public static class Employee<T extends Account> {
        private String name;
        private T account;
    }

    @Data
    public static abstract class Account {
        private final String type;
        protected Account(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class CurrentAccount extends Account {
        private BigDecimal balance;
        private BigDecimal limit;
        public CurrentAccount() {
            super("C");
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class SavingAccount extends Account {
        private BigDecimal balance;
        public SavingAccount() {
            super("S");
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "empListener", topics = "employees")
    public void listen(Employee<Account> e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("employees").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Employee> template) {
        return args -> {
            Employee<CurrentAccount> emp1 = new Employee<>();
            emp1.setName("someOneWithACurrentAccount");
            CurrentAccount currentAccount = new CurrentAccount();
            currentAccount.setBalance(BigDecimal.ONE);
            currentAccount.setLimit(BigDecimal.TEN);
            emp1.setAccount(currentAccount);
            template.send("employees", emp1);
            Employee<SavingAccount> emp2 = new Employee<>();
            emp2.setName("someOneWithASavingAccount");
            SavingAccount savingAccount = new SavingAccount();
            savingAccount.setBalance(BigDecimal.ONE);
            emp2.setAccount(savingAccount);
            template.send("employees", emp2);
        };
    }

    private static final JavaType withCurrent = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructParametricType(Employee.class, CurrentAccount.class);

    private static final JavaType withSaving = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructParametricType(Employee.class, SavingAccount.class);

    public static JavaType determineType(String topic, byte[] data, Headers headers) throws IOException {
        if (JsonPath.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "$.account.type").equals("C")) {
            return withCurrent;
        }
        else {
            return withSaving;
        }
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.demo.JacksonApplication.determineType
```

Result

```
JacksonApplication.Employee(name=someOneWithACurrentAccount, account=JacksonApplication.CurrentAccount(balance=1, limit=10))
JacksonApplication.Employee(name=someOneWithASavingAccount, account=JacksonApplication.SavingAccount(balance=1))
```

POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jackson</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT2**

And here is an example that conveys the type hint in a header instead...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class JacksonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JacksonApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Data
    public static class Employee<T extends Account> {
        private String name;
        private T account;
    }

    @Data
    public static abstract class Account {
    }

    @Data
    public static class CurrentAccount extends Account {
        private BigDecimal balance;
        private BigDecimal limit;
    }

    @Data
    public static class SavingAccount extends Account {
        private BigDecimal balance;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "empListener", topics = "employees")
    public void listen(Employee<Account> e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("employees").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Employee> template) {
        return args -> {
            Employee<CurrentAccount> emp1 = new Employee<>();
            emp1.setName("someOneWithACurrentAccount");
            CurrentAccount currentAccount = new CurrentAccount();
            currentAccount.setBalance(BigDecimal.ONE);
            currentAccount.setLimit(BigDecimal.TEN);
            emp1.setAccount(currentAccount);
            template.send("employees", emp1);
            Employee<SavingAccount> emp2 = new Employee<>();
            emp2.setName("someOneWithASavingAccount");
            SavingAccount savingAccount = new SavingAccount();
            savingAccount.setBalance(BigDecimal.ONE);
            emp2.setAccount(savingAccount);
            template.send("employees", emp2);
        };
    }

    private static final JavaType withCurrent = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructParametricType(Employee.class, CurrentAccount.class);

    private static final JavaType withSaving = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructParametricType(Employee.class, SavingAccount.class);

    public static JavaType determineType(String topic, byte[] data, Headers headers) throws IOException {
        if (headers.lastHeader("accountType").value()[0] == 'C') {
            return withCurrent;
        }
        else {
            return withSaving;
        }
    }

    public static class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Employee<?>> {

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(String topic, Headers headers, Employee<?> emp) {
            headers.add(new RecordHeader("accountType",
                    new byte[] { (byte) (emp.getAccount() instanceof CurrentAccount ? 'C' : 'S')}));
            return super.serialize(topic, headers, emp);
        }

    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=com.example.demo2.JacksonApplication.MySerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.demo2.JacksonApplication.determineType
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary, I have tried below but somehow I am not able access child class properties. While setting up account object casting the to specific account type. Using lombok annotations. 
Could you please help
```
Employee {
private Account account;
}

Account {
private String accountNo;
}

SavingAccount extends Account{
private BigDecimal balance;
}

CurrentAccount extends Account{
private BigDecimal balance;
}
```

Comment: I added a complete example.

Comment: I added another example that conveys the type hint in a header, which avoids using JsonPath to extract the type.

Answer (score 0):

This annotation solved my problem

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property = "@class")
private T account
```

it binds defined class for generic to the field